# pprint symbol already refers to user

Tags: clojure

how to handle the name collision/shadowing  in my test project in Windows? 
The *project.clj* contains the following lib declarations:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
        [incanter/incanter-core "1.5.4"]
        [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.3"]
        ]
```

And once i start the *repl* i am adding:

```
user=> (use 'incanter.core) ;the answer is nil
user=> (use 'clojure.data.json) 
WARNING: read already refers to: #'clojure.core/read in namespace: user, being r
eplaced by: #'clojure.data.json/read

IllegalStateException pprint already refers to: #'clojure.pprint/pprint in names
pace: user  clojure.lang.Namespace.warnOrFailOnReplace (Namespace.java:88)
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could tell `use` to rename or shadow the functions, but the best way is probably to `require` the namespace by a shorter name rather than `use`ing it, i.e.

```
(require '[clojure.data.json :as json])
```

will allow you to use its functions by the names `json/read`, `json/pprint`, ...

Comment: Not only does this work, it is the preferred way to utilize a namespace. `use` leads to code that is hard to maintain (it makes it harder to know when you can remove a dependency, makes it harder to track down the definitions of the functions you are calling, and makes it harder to split functionality into another namespace).